# toolbar выравнивание

Tags: android, toolbar

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откуда берется верхний зазор? Почему Tittle и Иконка ровняются по центру, а back кнопка и меню нет? Такое ощущение что все элементы живут своей жизнью. Есть ли вообще смысл использовать ToolBar или лучше юзать ActionBar? Не проще ли самому создать лейаут с нужными элементами похожий на ToolBar?

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: А если добавить `android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"`?

Comment: Без изменений..

Comment: Вы уже задавали вопрос с иконками. Сделайте их правильного размера и они будут располагаться четко по центру. Вот эти перемещения практически всегда из-за неправильного размера иконок. ActionBar и Toolbar это практически одно и тоже в смысле отображения. Самому делать свой велосипед конечно можно, но смысл тратить на это время ?

Comment: И да. Размер иконок задается в dp а не в px. Иконка должна быть представлена в необходимых разрешениях (обычно это hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi). И вот когда у вас для каждой иконки будет правильный набор правильного размера все отцентрируется и выровняется.

Comment: После вашего предыдущего совета я нарезал иконки с помощью сервиса http://shreyasachar.com/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html . И полученный результат(парки hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi) закинул res. Я даже вместо иконок просто создал shape.(подгрузил новое фото)